# Wordpress Google Maps

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have an issue with my google maps for wordpress where, the map loads jsut fine on the properties page however it does not pin point the correct address.

When a new property is added, you are required to enter an address and click "find address" then the map would show the pin pointed location, however of recent, the pin pointed location is some random point which doesn't change and the google map in the property editor side does not even show.

Can someone please assist me in making the "find address" work.

And in addition, this is the console error I receive:

```
post.php?post=3030&action=edit:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.riverdalep.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=3030&action=edit' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDWQpWFUygctd8GqZcnFnzsa9mrm7JGbqY&ver=4.9.8'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

map.js?ver=4.3.1:34 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined
at Object.initLatLng (map.js?ver=4.3.1:34)
at Object.init (map.js?ver=4.3.1:22)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (map.js?ver=4.3.1:179)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (map.js?ver=4.3.1:178)
at i (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2)
at Function.ready (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload&ver=4.9.8:2)
```

This is the link to the website:

https://www.riverdalep.com/property/wonderful-shop-space-in-ngara-to-let/

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are having insecure HTTP references in your HTTPS site. Change Google Maps script to load from HTTPS - `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDWQpWFUygctd8GqZcnFnzsa9mrm7JGbqY&ver=4.9.8`. Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @outsource WordPress, I just installed an SSL content fixer plugin and that thankfully resolved it.